# How to fix error 403 while using TwitterSearch

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to acquire data from Twitter using TwitterSearch. however, that's an error message about not being allowed access.
I already have a developer account and valid tokens, so how can I fix this?
Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import json
from TwitterSearch import *

def test():
    consumer_key = "..." 
    consumer_secret = "..."

    access_token = "..."
    access_token_secret = "..."


    ts = TwitterSearch(
        consumer_key = consumer_key,
        consumer_secret = consumer_secret, 
        access_token = access_token, 
        access_token_secret = access_token_secret
    )


    tso = TwitterSearchOrder()
    tso.set_keywords(['biometria','validacao'], or_operator = True)
    tso.set_language('pt')

    for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
        print('created at: ',tweet['created_at'], 'User id: ', tweet[id_str],'Tweet: ',tweet['text'])
```

test()

and here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/arielserafim/Documents/7 semestre/ITRACtwitter.py", line 39, in <module>
ts = TwitterSearch(
File "/home/arielserafim/.local/lib/python3.10/site- 
packages/TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.py", line 118, in __init__
self.authenticate(True)
File "/home/arielserafim/.local/lib/python3.10/site- 
packages/TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.py", line 170, in authenticate
self.check_http_status(r.status_code)
File "/home/arielserafim/.local/lib/python3.10/site- 
packages/TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.py", line 184, in check_http_status
raise TwitterSearchException(http_status,
TwitterSearch.TwitterSearchException.TwitterSearchException: Error 403: ('Forbidden: 
The request is understood, but', 'it has been refused or access is not allowed')
```

Comment: you probably need to beg twitter for permission because they control the API...

Comment: Do you have essential access or elevated? That is quite an old library (not updated in 4 years) and uses the legacy version of the Twitter API, not the current v2.